# SDL web 8 Content Manager Explorer Interface shows zero publications

Tags: cme, web8

After installation of Content Manager when i opened the CME Interface it shows content management section empty with no default publications at all. I was expecting default publications will be available which have set of folders with default template, schema , TBB to be used for development. Not getting any error on the browser or CME UI. please share what could be the possible reason for this; thanks

Answer (score 8):

A freshly installed system has no publications. You will need to create these yourself to match your own business needs and technical requirements.

If you are keen to have some ready-made items (including publications) as a starting point for development, you should look at the [Digital Experience Accelerator](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6), which is a framework that you can install in your freshly installed Web 8 system, and includes ready-made code and many examples of good practice.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above you will not get any publication after a fresh installation of CM & CM DB. Please use following link to create the publication(s).

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-7092FE4F-C925-4898-9670-DF2437F63F87

**Note:** after creating first publication create "structure group" after that only you will be able to create child publications.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answers, to create default templates, TBB, schema etc. (if you are not willing to use DXA); you can use SDL Web Template Builder tool and choose "Create default building blocks" option from "Tools" menu as shown below:

[image]

Further, my suggestion is that before you really start rushing for the development, you must have done following exercise before and implement them in SDL Web CMS:

- Brainstorming and Concluding on the Blueprint Hierarchy
- Brainstorming and Finalizing on the Content Models
- Implementing the Blueprint Hierarchy in the CMS
- Implementing Schema based on Content Models

I hope this helps